# how to make input disabled in react using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have 2 inputs on the form. I am using React.js and Twitter Bootstrap.

The intended behavior is:

When an input is typed in on either of the form input fields, another input field should not accept any input (or be `disabled`).

I am using FormControl from Bootstrap.

How should I achieve this in this React.js/Bootstrap setting?

Comment: I have 2 FormGroup
    <FormGroup controlId={this.props.id}> 
    <ControlLabel>{this.props.label}</ControlLabel> 
    <FormControl {...this.props} /> 
    </FormGroup>

Comment: What do you mean by disabled?

Comment: use state `isDisabled` in first input then `onKeyDown` second you `true` the state

Comment: I have 2 inputs and button and I can write information only in one input, the second becomes disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `disabled` property. You can do something like this:

```
class MyForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      focused: undefined,
    }
  }
  onFocus(id){
    this.setState({
      focused: id
    });
  }
  onBlur(){
    this.setState({
      focused: undefined,
    });
  }
  render(){
    const { focused } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormControl type="text" onFocus={() => this.onFocus(1)} onBlur={this.onBlur} disabled={focused && focused !== 1}/>
            <FormControl type="text" onFocus={() => this.onSecondFocus(2)} onBlur={this.onBlur} disabled={focused && focused !== 2}/>
          </FormGroup>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyForm;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/yPBvrOvKg

Comment: Thank you/ And if I want to desabled input if the first input has some information? I have 2 inputs and button and I can write information only in one input

Comment: Just change `onFocus` to `onChange` and check there length of input value, if it's > 0 you disable another input, else enable.
I have edited [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yPBvrOvKg)

Comment: And if i have 2 components. in first i have method
 handleInputChange = inputId => event => {
        this.setState({
            [inputId]: event.target.value
        });
    };

and in second component i have in props this.state.input1 and this.state.input2.
how in this case?

Comment: Could you ask by another way? I don't understand the last question, if it's question

Comment: i have this situation https://codesandbox.io/s/Q2gp7Ky5
2 components(they are in index.js and Hello.js) and one method handleInputChange. How in this way?

Comment: It's rather difficult to navigate in your project, because I do not have all the components. If fields in different components you do the same, you just sent `isFirstDisabled`,` isSecondDisabled` and `handleChage` with` props`.

Comment: and if I want to hidden placeholder of the input when it is disabled